# Avoid decrease of product quantity when the order status is still "Process"

Tags: php, prestashop, inventory, product-quantity

How to avoid decreasing of a product quantity when it's still in the "Process" and update when the order was shipped or delivered?

I've edited this part of code in `orderdetail.php` and add this `$id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_PREPARATION')` in the if statement. Yes, the quantity doesn't decrease when it's processed but when shipped it also doesn't decrease. please help I'm stuck in here.

```
protected function checkProductStock($product, $id_order_state)
{
    if ($id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_CANCELED') && $id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_ERROR') && $id_order_state != Configuration::get('PS_OS_PREPARATION')) {
        $update_quantity = true;
        if (!StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['id_product'])) {
            $update_quantity = StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['id_product'], $product['id_product_attribute'], -(int)$product['cart_quantity']);
        }

        if ($update_quantity) {
            $product['stock_quantity'] -= $product['cart_quantity'];
        }

        if ($product['stock_quantity'] < 0 && Configuration::get('PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT')) {
            $this->outOfStock = true;
        }
        Product::updateDefaultAttribute($product['id_product']);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is why I don't use pre-built items but... The reason why it's not decreasing is that the stock is not checked when the status is changed to "shipped" (or whatever). Why would it? You need to find the code that changes the status and add the check there - although what you would do if the stock were invalid is a little baffling - presumably prevent the status change but if you're already shipping it...

Answer (score 0):

An OrderDetail object is only created once for each Order and will not be updated after that even when you change the Order State. So when your OrderDetail object is created, with your modification it will not update the stock because it doesn't have the right state. And when you later change the Order State the method `checkProductStock` will never be called again.

You can create a custom module hooked on `actionOrderStatusPostUpdate` (witch is triggered inside `changeIdOrderState()` method of class `OrderHistory()`. In your module you will copy the `checkProductStock()` method and call it from the hook if the state is "shipped".

---

**EDIT**

If you want to add it directly in core:

Edit `classes/order/OrderHistory.php`

In method `changeIdOrderState()` change the last lines:

```php
    // executes hook
    Hook::exec('actionOrderStatusPostUpdate', array('newOrderStatus' => $new_os, 'id_order' => (int)$order->id, ), null, false, true, false, $order->id_shop);

    // Here change 4 to the desired id_order_state
    if ($new_order_state == 4)
    {
        $virtual_products = $order->getVirtualProducts();
        foreach ($virtual_products as $virtual_product)
        {
            $this->checkProductStock($virtual_product['product_id'], $new_order_state);
        }
    }

    ShopUrl::resetMainDomainCache();
}
```

After that add a new method in this class:

```php
protected function checkProductStock($product, $id_order_state)
{
    $update_quantity = true;
    if (!StockAvailable::dependsOnStock($product['product_id']))
    {
        StockAvailable::updateQuantity($product['product_id'], $product['product_attribute_id'], -(int)$product['product_quantity']);
    }

    Product::updateDefaultAttribute($product['product_id']);
}
```

This code has not been tested.

---

I advise you to do it in an override:

Create a new file in `/overrides/classes/order/OrderHistory.php` witch contains those two methods and change the class definition to `class OrderHistory extends OrderHistoryCore {`, you will have to delete `/cache/class_index.php` after adding this file.

Comment: Feel free to ask more informations if it's not clear.

Comment: Is there a way editing it in the core? cause I have no idea yet in creating module. By the way thank you! you are the only one responds to this question I post it in other forum but no luck. Thank you, hope you can still help me.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please take into account my advise to use overrides instead of editing core files. [How does overrides works in Prestashop 1.6](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)

Comment: after adding your code then try to confirm the order in frontend it gives me an error "Cart cannot be loaded or an order has already been placed using this cart" I put the `function checkproductstock` after the  `ShopUrl::resetMainDomainCache();
}` is it right? I really appreciate your help

Comment: sorry disregard the previous error it was on my part. It's not giving me an error but the quantity doesn't update too